# Random Geometry Assignment (Beginner Python)

Tags: python

The problem I have is trying to make my shape files have random locations and size, without having to put the definitions in a for loop. Here are my classes.

```
# Module imports
import math
import turtle as t

# Class Definitions
class Circle:

    def __init__(self,x=0,y=0,r=0):
        self.center = Point(x,y)
        self.radius = r

    def circumference(self):
        result = (self.radius * 2) * math.pi
        return result

    def area(self):
        result = (self.radius ** 2) * math.pi
        return result

    def draw(self,fill_color,pen_color,pen_width):
        t.color(pen_color)
        t.fillcolor(fill_color)
        t.pensize(pen_width)
        t.penup()
        t.goto(self.center.x,self.center.y)
        t.pendown()
        t.begin_fill()
        t.circle(self.radius)
        t.end_fill()
        t.penup()


class Point:
    """Represents a point with an x and y coordinate"""

    def __init__(self, x=0, y=0):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y

    def show(self):
        print "(%d, %d)" % (self.x, self.y)

    def move_to(self,x,y):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y

    def distance(self,p):
        dx = self.x - p.x
        dy = self.y - p.y
        dist = math.sqrt(dx**2 + dy**2)
        return dist


class Rectangle:
    "represented with upper left corner as a Point, width, height"""

    def __init__(self,x=0,y=0,width=100,height=100):
        self.corner = Point(x,y)
        self.width = width
        self.height = height

    def go_to(self,x,y):
        self.corner.move_to(x,y)

    def area(self):
        result = self.width * self.height
        return result

    def perimeter(self):
        result = 2*self.width + 2*self.height
        return result

    def draw(self,fill_color,pen_color,pen_width):
        t.color(pen_color)
        t.fillcolor(fill_color)
        t.pensize(pen_width)
        t.penup()
        t.goto(self.corner.x,self.corner.y)
        t.pendown()
        t.begin_fill()
        t.goto(self.corner.x + self.width,self.corner.y)
        t.goto(self.corner.x + self.width,self.corner.y - self.height)
        t.goto(self.corner.x,self.corner.y - self.height)
        t.goto(self.corner.x,self.corner.y)
        t.end_fill()
        t.penup()


class Segment:

    def __init__(self,x1=0,y1=0,x2=100,y2=0):
        self.start = Point(x1,y1)
        self.end = Point(x2,y2)

    def length(self):
        return self.start.distance(self.end)

    def draw(self,pen_color,pen_width):
        t.color(pen_color)
        t.pensize(pen_width)
        t.penup()
        t.goto(self.start.x,self.start.y)
        t.pendown()
        t.goto(self.end.x,self.end.y)
        t.penup()


class Triangle:

    def __init__(self,x1=0,y1=0,x2=0,y2=0,x3=0,y3=0):
        self.start = Point(x1,y1)
        self.second = Point(x2,y2)
        self.third = Point(x3,y3)
        self.segmentf = Segment(x1,y1,x2,y2)
        self.segments = Segment(x2,y2,x3,y3)
        self.segmentt = Segment(x3,y3,x1,y1)

    def area(self):
        a = self.segmentf.length()
        b = self.segments.length()
        c = self.segmentt.length()
        s = (a + b + c) / 2
        result = (s*(s-a)*(s-b)*(s-c)) ** 0.5
        return result

    def perimeter(self):
        a = self.segmentf.length()
        b = self.segments.length()
        c = self.segmentt.length()
        result = a + b + c
        return result

    def draw(self,fill_color,pen_color,pen_width):
        t.color(pen_color)
        t.fillcolor(fill_color)
        t.pensize(pen_width)
        t.penup()
        t.goto(self.start.x,self.start.y)
        t.pendown()
        t.begin_fill()
        t.goto(self.second.x,self.second.y)
        t.goto(self.third.x,self.third.y)
        t.goto(self.start.x,self.start.y)
        t.end_fill()
        t.penup()
```

And here is my main function:

```
# Module imports
import math
import turtle
import random 
from Suter_Andrew_shapesfinal import *

# Globals
MAX_S = 50

# List Definitions
r = Rectangle(random.randint(-100,100),random.randint(-100,100),random.randint(0,100),random.randint(0,100))
t = Triangle(random.randint(-100,100),random.randint(-100,100),random.randint(-100,100),random.randint(-100,100),random.randint(-100,100),random.randint(-100,100))
c = Circle(random.randint(-100,100),random.randint(-100,100),random.randint(0,100))

shapes = [r,t,c]
colors = ["blue","green","red","purple","pink","yellow","orange","black","white"]

# Main body
for i in range(MAX_S):
    s_choice = random.choice(shapes)
    c_choice = random.choice(colors)
    if s_choice == r:
        r.draw(c_choice,c_choice,random.randint(0,10))
    elif s_choice == t:
        t.draw(c_choice,c_choice,random.randint(0,10))
    elif s_choice == c:
        c.draw(c_choice,c_choice,random.randint(0,10))

turtle.mainloop()
```

The function works fine, but the problem is the definitions at the top. Thanks for reading!

Comment: Can you give a better description on the error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to have random definition of a shape for each time through the loop, you're going to have to put the instantiation of it inside the for loop. There's no way around this. If you create the instantiation outside the loop, then there'll only be one and you'll end up reusing the same one in all cases (as you've seen).

```
# Module imports
import math
import turtle
import random 
from Suter_Andrew_shapesfinal import *

randint = random.randint

# Globals
MAX_S = 50

# List Definitions
shapes = [Rectangle, Triangle, Circle]
colors = ["blue", "green", "red", "purple", "pink", "yellow", "orange", "black", "white"]

# Main body
for i in range(MAX_S):
    s_choice = random.choice(shapes)
    c_choice = random.choice(colors)
    if s_choice == Rectangle:
        r = Rectangle(*([randint(-100, 100) for x in range(2)] + [randint(0, 100) for x in range(2)]))
        r.draw(c_choice, c_choice, random.randint(0, 10))
    elif s_choice == Triangle:
        t = Triangle(*[randint(-100, 100) for x in range(6)])
        t.draw(c_choice, c_choice, random.randint(0, 10))
    elif s_choice == Circle:
        c = Circle(*([randint(-100, 100) for x in range(2)] + [randint(0, 100)]))
        c.draw(c_choice, c_choice, random.randint(0, 10))

turtle.mainloop()
```

I've also simplified the arguments bit of this a bit using list comprehension to generate a list of random.randints and then using the `*` in front of a list when passing it to a function unpacks the list into each parameter automatically.

Comment: `random.randint(-100, 100)` all over the place makes my eyes bleed